# Dependency Injection and JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection, jboss, cdi

Class 1: Repository.java:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Repository {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public Term findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(Term.class, id);
    }
}
```

Class 2: Word.java

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Word {

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private Repository repository;

    private Term term;

    public Word() {

    }

    public Word(Long id) {

        try{
            term = this.findTermById(id);       
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @Named
    public Term getTerm() {

        return term;
    }

    public Term findTermById(Long id) {

        Term term = repository.findById(id);

        if(term==null) {
            log.info("Can't find this word from database: " + term);
        }

        return term;
    }
}
```

Class 3: Resources.java

```
public class Resources {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public FacesContext produceFacesContext() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }
}
```

The problem with these two classes is that, when running the server, it throws an NullPointerException at the line:

```
Term term = repository.findById(id);
```

which means the injection of the object 'repository' failed, since debugging shows that "repository=null".

```
@Inject
private Repository repository;
```

Why does the injection is unsuccessful? Thank you.

Comment: How do you get a reference to a Word instance? What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: The problem is in your `Word` constructor - you want to use dependency, but in constructor they are not yet injected. Don't use constructors in CDI, move all logic from there to a method with annotation `@PostConstruct`. Also annotate your `Resource` class with `@Dependent` if you meet any further problems (if a class has `@Produces` method which takes `InjectionPoint` parameter it **has to** be dependent scoped).

Comment: @Geinmachi, the problem is how do I pass the parameter "Id" to the Word object, in order to create it? I can move the constructor to a PostConstruct method, but when to call this method to do the initialization?

Comment: That's the other question. You should not create managed beans by `new`. If you do so (I guess you do by having constructor with parameter) then it is not managed by container and nothing will be injected (lifecycle also fails). You should show where do you use this constructor and maybe consider using `@Produces` method instead.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. I will change the design.

Answer (score 1):

As @Geinmachi said, you are calling it in the constructor but you are not injecting it in the constructor but on field level which is not initialized until @PostConstruct.

You can use constructor injection to inject the repository as a parameter but instead you should not be manually instantiating Word but through CDI injection as well.

```
@Inject
public Word(Repository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}
```

In general a constructors should never be doing actions (like the db lookup you are doing), it is very bad practice because no one knows the behavior from outside plus you won't have a transaction going during @Inject. Also you should not manually instantiate CDI beans because their lifecycle is managed by CDI and are designed to be used through @Inject.

Also you will have concurrency issues by having an Applicationscoped entitymanager, it should be requestscoped.

Comment: how to do this, "You can use constructor injection to inject the repository as a parameter "?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have full stacktrace? I think the NullPointerException might come from `private EntityManager em;` being null in your Repository bean.

CDI doesn't see your class Resources, as it is not defined bean. (As far as I can tell from the code.)

Comment: Repository field itself is null, so entity manager can't be there. It should be injected by `@Produces` field in `Resources` class anyway.